# Ruby plist gem generates carEt ^M at the end of the line, How to Remove?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, encoding, plist

I'm using this [plist gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/plist) to generate a plist file, which [my Rails application](https://github.com/FromStoneage/munkiserver) will output to user if the request is `http://myrailsapp/something.plist`

the code responsible for this is pretty simple. (controller)

```
if @package.present?
   format.html
   format.plist { render :text => @package.to_plist }
```

view it im Vim, gives

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>uninstall_script</key>
        <string>#!/bin/sh^M
        ^M
        echo &quot;Test&quot;^M
        ^M
        exit 0^M
        </string>
        <key>uninstallable</key>
        <true/>
        <key>version</key>
        <string>4.7</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

On every string line end with a ^M

when I try to debugger this in rails console, it outputs just fine

```
<key>uninstall_script</key>\n\t<string>#!/bin/sh\r\n\t\r\n\techo &quot;Test&quot;\r\n\t\r\n\texit 0\r\n\t</string>\n\t
```

No ^M to be find. So any suggestions on where I should look for this issues ?

When the plist that has ^M at the end of the line, another program that reply on this plist doesn't read it properly. And when I try to remove the ^M manually it works just fine.

Comment: That `^M` is a Ctrl+M (AKA carriage return, CR, `\r`). What is using CR-LF as an end-of-line?

Comment: oh so the `^M` is actually `\r` ? in this case ? If that's the case, I can just remove all the `\r` and would just resolve the issue ?
ps. I have no idea what's using CR-LF in this case, How do I find out ?

Comment: Yes, `^M` is how vim displays `\r`. How does your shell script get from disk to the plist file? Does your script have CR-LF EOLs on disk?

Comment: @muistooshort I have a textarea let the user to input the script. my rails app repackage the script with other info into a plist. So all the `\n\r` I imagine it's all from the plist plugin.

Comment: The CR-LF stuff is almost certainly coming from the `<textarea>`, you should be normalizing your EOLs when you read the `<textarea>` text out of the incoming request. OSX uses just an LF so I doubt the plist library would add the CRs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short)

pointing out that `\r` is actually the cause of `^M`. In that case, I've just fixed this bug !!

Pretty simple fix just add the following inline to over write the `to_plist` method

```
plist.gsub(/\r\n?/, "\n")
```

And that just did the job I wanted